# Help with Travel Guide Setup

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, customization

I have setup a travel guide site with wordpress and would like some assistance on how I have set it up before I venture to far making it hard to change the structure.

**Custom Taxonomy** 
**Area** (SOHO, DUMBO, Chinatown, Midtown ETC)
**Subway Station** (Station 1, Station 2, Station 3)
**Facilities** (Disabled Access, Shop, Toilets)
**Suitability** (adult, kids, family)

I then have categories as follows (Sub Categories)

Attraction (Museum, Sightseeing, Park)
Accommodation (Hotel, B&B, Hostel)
Deal

I would create a post as follows
**Post Name:** Central Park
**Category:** Attraction/Park
**Area:** Midtown
**Suitability:** Adults, Kids, Families
**Train Station:** Columbus Circle
**Facilities:** Toilets

When I view the taxonomy for instance midtown, I would like to list all the attractions then all the accommodations and then all the deals that related only to midtown. Or visit the families taxonomy and see all accommodation, attractions and deals that are suitable for Families.

My question is would I be better making Attraction, Accommodation and Deal as custom post types instead of categories.

It the longer term is it easier to separate the posts into the different custom post types?

Can I then run a query to show all attractions in midtown suitable for family's. And a separate one to shoe all deals for accommodation near Columbus Circle.

Has anyone done anything similar? Would love some feedback and ideas on how to structure the site.

Also does anyone have a better description than Suitability, this is who the attraction is suitable for.

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0):

I would do them as custom posts so that you can loop in relevant 'accommodation' to 'attractions' and vice versa.

'Deal' I'd be tempted to do as advanced custom fields in those post types. But then it could work as a post type too.

Suitability can be categories.

Work it out on paper first. Check what you need to do for each and how they'll relate to each other.